# Keyloggers and Virtual Machines

Tags: security, operating-system, virtualization, keylogger

I want to test some keyloggers in order to see how they work.

If my host OS is clean, and I install the keyloggers on a guest OS running in VirtualBox, will the keylogger be able to log the keystrokes and screenshots in the HOST OS?

I think I know the answer to this question but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your VMs are broken, key/screen-loggers will be fully contained in the VMs and will gain no access to the host OS keyboard/screen data that's outside of the VM.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought but I had to be sure :)

Comment: Security guys use VMs when studying or testing exploits and countermeasures.